# Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" at Object.InvalidResponse

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs, react, error

I am trying to make a voting system using blockchain. I am using ganache to deploy the smart contracts.
I made connection using web3.ts

```
import Web3 from "web3";
import data from "../build/contracts/Election.json";

export const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1.7545");

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1.7545");
try {
    console.log(web3.eth.accounts);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

const contract = require("@truffle/contract");

const ElectionContract = contract(data);

ElectionContract.setProvider(provider);

export default ElectionContract;
```

my backend file is as follows

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import ElectionContract from "../../web3";

export default async (_: Request, res: Response) => {
  let instance=null;
  try{
    instance = await ElectionContract.deployed();
    console.log(instance);
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }finally{
    const status = await instance.getStatus();
    console.log("hello");
    return res.send({ status });
  }
};
```

whenever i run this it gives error
[image]